# Load fragment inside DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a `DrawerLayout` with first child as a `FrameLayout` and the second child as a `ListView` which will be the drawer.

Now in the activity, I have used the support fragment manager to load a fragment in the FrameLayout in the DrawerLayout.

The error code is

```
IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. Use removeView() on the child
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you inflated your first fragment. It is usually caused by inflating wrong constructor so be sure to inflate the correct constructor.

```
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider to support source code because without it it's a matter of guessing.

As the crash log states - you are trying to add a view that already has a parent view to another parent view, you can't do that, a view may have just a single ViewGroup parent view.

I'm guessing that in the instantiation of the fragment, when you creates a FragmentTransaction 
you're adding an id of a container view and after that trying to add the fragment to the FrameLayout.

The id you adding to FragmentTransaction must be the one of the FrameLayout.

For example:

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.add(R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
trans.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

the R.id.tabcontent should be the id of the intended fragment's container